# delimitMate not working on vim installed with Pathogen

Tags: vim, autocomplete, braces, pathogen

I'm trying to install delimitMate on vim version 7.3. I am using Pathogen. My other pathogen bundles work, so it is not a problem with my setup.

In fact, I've also tried auto-pairs and ClosePairs plugins too, and none of them work. I don't know why? Am I using it wrong? Shouldn't a matching paren simply follow when I put an opening paren (similar to sublime Text?)

The commands `:DelimitMateTest` and `:h delimitemate` works, so the script is being executed. It's just not actually autoclosing any parens, and I can't figure out why.

Here's the output file for `:DelimitMateTest`: http://pastebin.com/2WtHVZJL

Any ideas as to why I can't get paren completion from *any* plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: The DelimitMate issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/issues).

Comment: i want to make sure it's not something i'm doing wrong on my end, since none of the other autoparen plugins work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those of you who come across this problem in the future:

I had `set paste` in my `.vimrc`. This permanently disables several other features, and it was messing up key mappings. Simply remove it from your `.vimrc` and you should fix your problem.